# Able to start appium inspector and run the app over simulator using a .app file, but unable to do the same through a .ipa file over a real device

Tags: ios, ui-automation, appium, ios-ui-automation

I have no idea what went wrong, we were able to install the application on the iOS device before, but I changed my mac, and the error started appearing.

So I have no problems with running appium and the inspector over simulators using the .app file. The issue is only with trying to have appium run over real devices. 
I tried with a ipa that is of ad-hoc build, and .app files that were done with developer provisioning.

Im able to install the app over X-Code, but if I Run the same over appium, it gives either a fruitstrap crash error, and if the app is already installed on to the device and appium is run, it gives a "error: Failed to start an Appium session, err was: Error: Instruments crashed on startup". and the app starts up and closes instantly.

I have read almost all stack overflow pages on the error, and none of the solutions seem to help me solve this. :(

Error if app is already installed on the device :-

```
![Launching Appium with command: '/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node/bin/node' lib/server/main.js --command-timeout "7200" --platform-version "8.3" --platform-name "iOS" --app "com.indecomm.literaturelibrary" --udid "5fcdd3078c081abb666330066681c5f0c55d2a08" --device-name "Rohan"

info: Welcome to Appium v1.3.7 (REV 72fbfaa116d3d9f6a862600ee99cf02f6d0e2182)

info: Appium REST http interface listener started on 0.0.0.0:4723
info: \[debug\] Non-default server args: {"app":"com.indecomm.literaturelibrary","udid":"5fcdd3078c081abb666330066681c5f0c55d2a08","deviceName":"Rohan","platformName":"iOS","platformVersion":"8.3","defaultCommandTimeout":7200}
info: Console LogLevel: debug

info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}

info: \[debug\] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.3.7","revision":"72fbfaa116d3d9f6a862600ee99cf02f6d0e2182"}}}

info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 10.052 ms - 104 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.3.7","revision":"72fbfaa116d3d9f6a862600ee99cf02f6d0e2182"}}}

info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}

info: \[debug\] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.3.7","revision":"72fbfaa116d3d9f6a862600ee99cf02f6d0e2182"}}}

info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 5.375 ms - 104 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.3.7","revision":"72fbfaa116d3d9f6a862600ee99cf02f6d0e2182"}}}

info: --> GET /wd/hub/sessions {}
info: \[debug\] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":\[\]}
info: <-- GET /wd/hub/sessions 200 1.032 ms - 23 {"status":0,"value":\[\]}

info: --> POST /wd/hub/session {"desiredCapabilities":{"platformName":"iOS","platformVersion":"8.3","newCommandTimeout":"999999","automationName":"Appium","deviceName":"Rohan"}}
info: Client User-Agent string: Appium (unknown version) CFNetwork/720.3.13 Darwin/14.3.0 (x86_64)
info: \[debug\] App is an iOS bundle, will attempt to run as pre-existing
info: \[debug\] Creating new appium session 371dbdd4-3129-40ee-b102-4048d0ee998f

info: \[debug\] Removing any remaining instruments sockets
info: \[debug\] Cleaned up instruments socket /tmp/instruments_sock
info: \[debug\] Setting Xcode folder

info: \[debug\] Setting Xcode version

info: \[debug\] Setting iOS SDK Version

info: \[debug\] Getting sdk version from xcrun with a timeout

info: \[debug\] iOS SDK Version set to 8.3
info: \[debug\] Not checking whether simulator is available since we're on a real device
info: \[debug\] Detecting automation tracetemplate
info: \[debug\] Not auto-detecting udid, running on sim

info: \[debug\] Could not parse plist file (as binary) at /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/com.indecomm.literaturelibrary/en.lproj/Localizable.strings
info: Will try to parse the plist file as XML
info: \[debug\] Could not parse plist file (as XML) at /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/com.indecomm.literaturelibrary/en.lproj/Localizable.strings
warn: Could not parse app Localizable.strings assuming it doesn't exist
info: \[debug\] Creating instruments
info: On some xcode 6 platforms, instruments-without-delay does not work. If you experience this, you will need to re-run appium with the --native-instruments-lib flag
info: \[debug\] Preparing uiauto bootstrap
info: \[debug\] Dynamic bootstrap dir: /Users/rohanganapathy/Library/Application Support/appium/bootstrap
info: \[debug\] Dynamic env: {"nodePath":"/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node/bin/node","commandProxyClientPath":"/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-uiauto/bin/command-proxy-client.js","instrumentsSock":"/tmp/instruments_sock","interKeyDelay":null,"justLoopInfinitely":false,"autoAcceptAlerts":false,"autoDismissAlerts":false,"sendKeyStrategy":"grouped"}
info: \[debug\] Dynamic bootstrap code: // This file is automatically generated. Do not manually modify!
...
info: \[debug\] Dynamic bootstrap path: /Users/rohanganapathy/Library/Application Support/appium/bootstrap/bootstrap-d5a0fb924946d8d3.js
info: \[debug\] Reusing dynamic bootstrap: /Users/rohanganapathy/Library/Application Support/appium/bootstrap/bootstrap-d5a0fb924946d8d3.js
info: \[debug\] Getting device string from opts: {"forceIphone":false,"forceIpad":false,"xcodeVersion":"6.3.1","iOSSDKVersion":"8.3","deviceName":"Rohan","platformVersion":"8.3"}
info: \[debug\] fixDevice is on
info: \[debug\] Final device string is: 'Rohan (8.3 Simulator)'

info: \[debug\] Not setting device type since we're on a real device
info: \[debug\] Checking whether we need to set app preferences
info: \[debug\] Not setting iOS and app preferences since we're on a real device
info: \[debug\] Running ios sim reset flow
info: \[debug\] Killing the simulator process
info: \[debug\] Killall iOS Simulator
info: \[debug\] Killing any other simulator daemons
info: \[debug\] On a real device; cannot clean device state
info: \[debug\] Not setting locale because we're using a real device
info: \[debug\] No iOS / app preferences to set
info: \[debug\] Starting iOS device log capture via deviceconsole

info: \[debug\] Not pre-launching simulator

info: \[debug\] Creating iDevice object with udid 5fcdd3078c081abb666330066681c5f0c55d2a08

info: \[debug\] Checking app install status using: /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/build/fruitstrap/fruitstrap isInstalled --id 5fcdd3078c081abb666330066681c5f0c55d2a08 --bundle com.indecomm.literaturelibrary

info: \[debug\] App is installed.

info: \[debug\] fullReset not requested. No need to install.
info: \[debug\] Starting command proxy.

info: \[debug\] Instruments socket server started at /tmp/instruments_sock
info: \[debug\] Starting instruments
info: \[debug\] Instruments is at: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/instruments
info: Launching instruments
info: \[debug\] Attempting to run app on real device with UDID 5fcdd3078c081abb666330066681c5f0c55d2a08
info: \[debug\] Spawning instruments with command: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/instruments -t /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/PlugIns/AutomationInstrument.xrplugin/Contents/Resources/Automation.tracetemplate -D /tmp/appium-instruments/instrumentscli0.trace -w 5fcdd3078c081abb666330066681c5f0c55d2a08 com.indecomm.literaturelibrary -e UIASCRIPT "/Users/rohanganapathy/Library/Application Support/appium/bootstrap/bootstrap-d5a0fb924946d8d3.js" -e UIARESULTSPATH /tmp/appium-instruments
info: \[debug\] And extra without-delay env: {}
info: \[debug\] And launch timeouts (in ms): {"global":90000}

info: \[debug\] \[INST STDERR\] 2015-05-13 12:35:32.683 instruments\[10692:1844813\] WebKit Threading Violation - initial use of WebKit from a secondary thread.

info: \[debug\] \[INST STDERR\] Instruments Trace Error : Target failed to run: Permission to debug com.indecomm.literaturelibrary was denied. The app must be signed with a development identity (e.g. iOS Developer).

info: \[debug\] \[INSTSERVER\] Instruments exited with code 253

info: \[debug\] Killall instruments

info: \[debug\] Instruments crashed on startup
info: \[debug\] Attempting to retry launching instruments, this is retry #1
info: \[debug\] Killall iOS Simulator

info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}

info: \[debug\] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.3.7","revision":"72fbfaa116d3d9f6a862600ee99cf02f6d0e2182"},"isShuttingDown":false},"sessionId":"371dbdd4-3129-40ee-b102-4048d0ee998f"}
info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 1.113 ms - 178 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.3.7","revision":"72fbfaa116d3d9f6a862600ee99cf02f6d0e2182"},"isShuttingDown":false},"sessionId":"371dbdd4-3129-40ee-b102-4048d0ee998f"}

info: Launching instruments

info: \[debug\] Attempting to run app on real device with UDID 5fcdd3078c081abb666330066681c5f0c55d2a08

info: \[debug\] Spawning instruments with command: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/instruments -t /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/PlugIns/AutomationInstrument.xrplugin/Contents/Resources/Automation.tracetemplate -D /tmp/appium-instruments/instrumentscli0.trace -w 5fcdd3078c081abb666330066681c5f0c55d2a08 com.indecomm.literaturelibrary -e UIASCRIPT "/Users/rohanganapathy/Library/Application Support/appium/bootstrap/bootstrap-d5a0fb924946d8d3.js" -e UIARESULTSPATH /tmp/appium-instruments
info: \[debug\] And extra without-delay env: {}
info: \[debug\] And launch timeouts (in ms): {"global":90000}

info: \[debug\] \[INST STDERR\] 2015-05-13 12:35:38.992 instruments\[10695:1844869\] WebKit Threading Violation - initial use of WebKit from a secondary thread.

info: \[debug\] \[INST STDERR\] Instruments Trace Error : Target failed to run: Permission to debug com.indecomm.literaturelibrary was denied. The app must be signed with a development identity (e.g. iOS Developer).

info: \[debug\] \[INSTSERVER\] Instruments exited with code 253

info: \[debug\] Killall instruments
info: \[debug\] Instruments crashed on startup
info: \[debug\] Attempting to retry launching instruments, this is retry #2
info: \[debug\] Killall iOS Simulator

info: Launching instruments

info: \[debug\] Attempting to run app on real device with UDID 5fcdd3078c081abb666330066681c5f0c55d2a08
info: \[debug\] Spawning instruments with command: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/instruments -t /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/PlugIns/AutomationInstrument.xrplugin/Contents/Resources/Automation.tracetemplate -D /tmp/appium-instruments/instrumentscli0.trace -w 5fcdd3078c081abb666330066681c5f0c55d2a08 com.indecomm.literaturelibrary -e UIASCRIPT "/Users/rohanganapathy/Library/Application Support/appium/bootstrap/bootstrap-d5a0fb924946d8d3.js" -e UIARESULTSPATH /tmp/appium-instruments
info: \[debug\] And extra without-delay env: {}
info: \[debug\] And launch timeouts (in ms): {"global":90000}

info: \[debug\] \[INST STDERR\] 2015-05-13 12:35:44.997 instruments\[10698:1844942\] WebKit Threading Violation - initial use of WebKit from a secondary thread.

info: \[debug\] \[INST STDERR\] Instruments Trace Error : Target failed to run: Permission to debug com.indecomm.literaturelibrary was denied. The app must be signed with a development identity (e.g. iOS Developer).

info: \[debug\] \[INSTSERVER\] Instruments exited with code 253

info: \[debug\] Killall instruments
info: \[debug\] Instruments crashed on startup
info: \[debug\] Attempting to retry launching instruments, this is retry #3
info: \[debug\] Killall iOS Simulator

info: Launching instruments

info: \[debug\] Attempting to run app on real device with UDID 5fcdd3078c081abb666330066681c5f0c55d2a08
info: \[debug\] Spawning instruments with command: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/instruments -t /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/PlugIns/AutomationInstrument.xrplugin/Contents/Resources/Automation.tracetemplate -D /tmp/appium-instruments/instrumentscli0.trace -w 5fcdd3078c081abb666330066681c5f0c55d2a08 com.indecomm.literaturelibrary -e UIASCRIPT "/Users/rohanganapathy/Library/Application Support/appium/bootstrap/bootstrap-d5a0fb924946d8d3.js" -e UIARESULTSPATH /tmp/appium-instruments
info: \[debug\] And extra without-delay env: {}
info: \[debug\] And launch timeouts (in ms): {"global":90000}

info: \[debug\] \[INST STDERR\] 2015-05-13 12:35:51.316 instruments\[10701:1845063\] WebKit Threading Violation - initial use of WebKit from a secondary thread.

info: \[debug\] \[INST STDERR\] Instruments Trace Error : Target failed to run: Permission to debug com.indecomm.literaturelibrary was denied. The app must be signed with a development identity (e.g. iOS Developer).

info: \[debug\] \[INSTSERVER\] Instruments exited with code 253

info: \[debug\] Killall instruments

info: \[debug\] Instruments crashed on startup
info: \[debug\] We exceeded the number of retries allowed for instruments to successfully start; failing launch
info: \[debug\] Stopping iOS log capture
info: \[debug\] Running ios sim reset flow
info: \[debug\] Killing the simulator process
info: \[debug\] Killall iOS Simulator
info: \[debug\] Killing any other simulator daemons
info: \[debug\] On a real device; cannot clean device state
info: \[debug\] Cleaning up appium session
info: \[debug\] Error: Instruments crashed on startup
    at Instruments.onInstrumentsExit (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-instruments/lib/instruments.js:389:31)
    at null.<anonymous> (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-instruments/lib/instruments.js:308:12)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1067:12)
info: \[debug\] Responding to client with error: {"status":33,"value":{"message":"A new session could not be created. (Original error: Instruments crashed on startup)","origValue":"Instruments crashed on startup"},"sessionId":null}

error: Failed to start an Appium session, err was: Error: Instruments crashed on startup

info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session 500 21928.427 ms - 182 

info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}

info: \[debug\] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.3.7","revision":"72fbfaa116d3d9f6a862600ee99cf02f6d0e2182"}}}
info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 1.723 ms - 104 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.3.7","revision":"72fbfaa116d3d9f6a862600ee99cf02f6d0e2182"}}}

info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}

info: \[debug\] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.3.7","revision":"72fbfaa116d3d9f6a862600ee99cf02f6d0e2182"}}}
info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 1.344 ms - 104 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.3.7","revision":"72fbfaa116d3d9f6a862600ee99cf02f6d0e2182"}}}

info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}

info: \[debug\] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.3.7","revision":"72fbfaa116d3d9f6a862600ee99cf02f6d0e2182"}}}

info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 1.144 ms - 104 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.3.7","revision":"72fbfaa116d3d9f6a862600ee99cf02f6d0e2182"}}}

info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}

info: \[debug\] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.3.7","revision":"72fbfaa116d3d9f6a862600ee99cf02f6d0e2182"}}}

info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 1.039 ms - 104 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.3.7","revision":"72fbfaa116d3d9f6a862600ee99cf02f6d0e2182"}}}

info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}

info: \[debug\] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.3.7","revision":"72fbfaa116d3d9f6a862600ee99cf02f6d0e2182"}}}
info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 1.202 ms - 104 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.3.7","revision":"72fbfaa116d3d9f6a862600ee99cf02f6d0e2182"}}}

info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}

info: \[debug\] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.3.7","revision":"72fbfaa116d3d9f6a862600ee99cf02f6d0e2182"}}}
info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 1.082 ms - 104 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.3.7","revision":"72fbfaa116d3d9f6a862600ee99cf02f6d0e2182"}}}
`][1]
```

Error if app is not installed in the device:-

```
Launching Appium with command: '/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node/bin/node' lib/server/main.js --command-timeout "7200" --platform-version "8.3" --platform-name "iOS" --app "com.indecomm.literaturelibrary" --udid "5fcdd3078c081abb666330066681c5f0c55d2a08" --device-name "Rohan"

info: Welcome to Appium v1.3.7 (REV 72fbfaa116d3d9f6a862600ee99cf02f6d0e2182)

info: Appium REST http interface listener started on 0.0.0.0:4723
info: [debug] Non-default server args: {"app":"com.indecomm.literaturelibrary","udid":"5fcdd3078c081abb666330066681c5f0c55d2a08","deviceName":"Rohan","platformName":"iOS","platformVersion":"8.3","defaultCommandTimeout":7200}
info: Console LogLevel: debug

info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}

info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.3.7","revision":"72fbfaa116d3d9f6a862600ee99cf02f6d0e2182"}}}

info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 11.393 ms - 104 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.3.7","revision":"72fbfaa116d3d9f6a862600ee99cf02f6d0e2182"}}}

info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}

info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.3.7","revision":"72fbfaa116d3d9f6a862600ee99cf02f6d0e2182"}}}
info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 3.277 ms - 104 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.3.7","revision":"72fbfaa116d3d9f6a862600ee99cf02f6d0e2182"}}}
info: --> GET /wd/hub/sessions {}
info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":[]}
info: <-- GET /wd/hub/sessions 200 1.075 ms - 23 {"status":0,"value":[]}

info: --> POST /wd/hub/session {"desiredCapabilities":{"platformName":"iOS","platformVersion":"8.3","newCommandTimeout":"999999","automationName":"Appium","deviceName":"Rohan"}}

info: Client User-Agent string: Appium (unknown version) CFNetwork/720.3.13 Darwin/14.3.0 (x86_64)
info: [debug] App is an iOS bundle, will attempt to run as pre-existing
info: [debug] Creating new appium session 9fd1be4f-aaeb-41c9-afd2-6947fa91babf
info: [debug] Removing any remaining instruments sockets
info: [debug] Cleaned up instruments socket /tmp/instruments_sock
info: [debug] Setting Xcode folder

info: [debug] Setting Xcode version

info: [debug] Setting iOS SDK Version

info: [debug] Getting sdk version from xcrun with a timeout

info: [debug] iOS SDK Version set to 8.3

info: [debug] Not checking whether simulator is available since we're on a real device
info: [debug] Detecting automation tracetemplate

info: [debug] Not auto-detecting udid, running on sim
info: [debug] Could not parse plist file (as binary) at /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/com.indecomm.literaturelibrary/en.lproj/Localizable.strings
info: Will try to parse the plist file as XML
info: [debug] Could not parse plist file (as XML) at /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/com.indecomm.literaturelibrary/en.lproj/Localizable.strings
warn: Could not parse app Localizable.strings assuming it doesn't exist
info: [debug] Creating instruments
info: On some xcode 6 platforms, instruments-without-delay does not work. If you experience this, you will need to re-run appium with the --native-instruments-lib flag
info: [debug] Preparing uiauto bootstrap
info: [debug] Dynamic bootstrap dir: /Users/rohanganapathy/Library/Application Support/appium/bootstrap
info: [debug] Dynamic env: {"nodePath":"/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node/bin/node","commandProxyClientPath":"/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-uiauto/bin/command-proxy-client.js","instrumentsSock":"/tmp/instruments_sock","interKeyDelay":null,"justLoopInfinitely":false,"autoAcceptAlerts":false,"autoDismissAlerts":false,"sendKeyStrategy":"grouped"}

info: [debug] Dynamic bootstrap code: // This file is automatically generated. Do not manually modify!
...
info: [debug] Dynamic bootstrap path: /Users/rohanganapathy/Library/Application Support/appium/bootstrap/bootstrap-d5a0fb924946d8d3.js
info: [debug] Reusing dynamic bootstrap: /Users/rohanganapathy/Library/Application Support/appium/bootstrap/bootstrap-d5a0fb924946d8d3.js
info: [debug] Getting device string from opts: {"forceIphone":false,"forceIpad":false,"xcodeVersion":"6.3.1","iOSSDKVersion":"8.3","deviceName":"Rohan","platformVersion":"8.3"}
info: [debug] fixDevice is on
info: [debug] Final device string is: 'Rohan (8.3 Simulator)'
info: [debug] Not setting device type since we're on a real device
info: [debug] Checking whether we need to set app preferences
info: [debug] Not setting iOS and app preferences since we're on a real device
info: [debug] Running ios sim reset flow
info: [debug] Killing the simulator process
info: [debug] Killall iOS Simulator
info: [debug] Killing any other simulator daemons

info: [debug] On a real device; cannot clean device state
info: [debug] Not setting locale because we're using a real device
info: [debug] No iOS / app preferences to set

info: [debug] Starting iOS device log capture via deviceconsole

info: [debug] Not pre-launching simulator

info: [debug] Creating iDevice object with udid 5fcdd3078c081abb666330066681c5f0c55d2a08

info: [debug] Checking app install status using: /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/build/fruitstrap/fruitstrap isInstalled --id 5fcdd3078c081abb666330066681c5f0c55d2a08 --bundle com.indecomm.literaturelibrary

info: [debug] App is not installed. Will try to install the app.

info: [debug] Installing app using cmd: /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/build/fruitstrap/fruitstrap install --id 5fcdd3078c081abb666330066681c5f0c55d2a08 --bundle "com.indecomm.literaturelibrary"

info: [debug] Cleaning up appium session

info: [debug] Error: Unable to install [com.indecomm.literaturelibrary] to device with id [5fcdd3078c081abb666330066681c5f0c55d2a08]. Error [Error: Command failed: /bin/sh -c /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/build/fruitstrap/fruitstrap install --id 5fcdd3078c081abb666330066681c5f0c55d2a08 --bundle "com.indecomm.literaturelibrary"
Assertion failed: (access(app_path, F_OK) == 0), function main, file fruitstrap.c, line 718.
]
    at /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/lib/devices/common.js:147:10
    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:751:5)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:1008:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (child_process.js:1176:11)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:107:17)
    at Pipe.close (net.js:476:12)
info: [debug] Responding to client with error: {"status":33,"value":{"message":"A new session could not be created. (Original error: Unable to install [com.indecomm.literaturelibrary] to device with id [5fcdd3078c081abb666330066681c5f0c55d2a08]. Error [Error: Command failed: /bin/sh -c /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/build/fruitstrap/fruitstrap install --id 5fcdd3078c081abb666330066681c5f0c55d2a08 --bundle \"com.indecomm.literaturelibrary\"\nAssertion failed: (access(app_path, F_OK) == 0), function main, file fruitstrap.c, line 718.\n])","origValue":"Unable to install [com.indecomm.literaturelibrary] to device with id [5fcdd3078c081abb666330066681c5f0c55d2a08]. Error [Error: Command failed: /bin/sh -c /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/build/fruitstrap/fruitstrap install --id 5fcdd3078c081abb666330066681c5f0c55d2a08 --bundle \"com.indecomm.literaturelibrary\"\nAssertion failed: (access(app_path, F_OK) == 0), function main, file fruitstrap.c, line 718.\n]"},"sessionId":null}

error: Failed to start an Appium session, err was: Error: Unable to install [com.indecomm.literaturelibrary] to device with id [5fcdd3078c081abb666330066681c5f0c55d2a08]. Error [Error: Command failed: /bin/sh -c /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/build/fruitstrap/fruitstrap install --id 5fcdd3078c081abb666330066681c5f0c55d2a08 --bundle "com.indecomm.literaturelibrary"
Assertion failed: (access(app_path, F_OK) == 0), function main, file fruitstrap.c, line 718.
]

info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session 500 2729.320 ms - 1002 

info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}

info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.3.7","revision":"72fbfaa116d3d9f6a862600ee99cf02f6d0e2182"}}}
info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 1.394 ms - 104 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.3.7","revision":"72fbfaa116d3d9f6a862600ee99cf02f6d0e2182"}}}

info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that the app must be signed with a developer profile for it to work on real ios devices.I had faced the same issue and it works after signing it with a development profile(u can get one from apple dev site for $99).

```
info: \[debug\] \[INST STDERR\] Instruments Trace Error : Target failed to run: Permission to debug com.indecomm.literaturelibrary was denied. The app must be signed with a development identity (e.g. iOS Developer).
```

pls refer to this for further details https://discuss.appium.io/t/the-app-must-be-signed-with-a-development-identity/2653